# Adding Environment.NewLine into filestream

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord.net

I am making a discord bot in a .net console app, and I struggled big time with stream writer so I am trying file stream, I am not having the same errors I had with stream writer, but I am having the problem off adding a new line,

```
string path = @"C:\PathWouldBeHere\Log.txt"; // path to file

using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    string dataasstring = $"[{DateTime.Now.Hour}:{DateTime.Now.Minute}][Log]{Context.User.Username}:  {Context.Message.Content}"; //your data
    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(dataasstring);
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

Now I know I can use `Environment.NewLine`, but I am a complete noob and have no idea where in the code I should put it. I know it's asking a bit but if someone could tweak my code just so that instead of it logging one thing (deleting the previous log), it adds a newline instead.

Comment: Please try `string dataasstring = $"...." + Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: string dataasstring = $"...." + Environment.NewLine; This doesn't work, Unfortunately still deleted the other line.

Comment: What do you mean "deleted the other line"? Which other line?

Comment: I did it twice, one minute between each other, IE [20:01] was first part (Time) and when I activated command at [20:02] it deleted [20:01] and replaced with [20:02]

Comment: How can you struggle with StreamWriter, but have no problem using FileStream? `using (StreamWriter wrt = File.CreateText(@"x:\what\ever\file.txt")) { wrt.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.Hour}:{DateTime.Now.Minute}][Log]{Context.User.Username}:  {Context.Message.Content}"); }` What exactly were you struggling with in regard to StreamWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `File.Create`, which creates a new file at the location and deletes any file that already exists there. What you want instead is to use the `FileStream` constructor with the `FileMode.Append` flag:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
{
    string dataasstring = $"[{DateTime.Now.Hour}:{DateTime.Now.Minute}][Log]{Context.User.Username}:  {Context.Message.Content}{Environment.NewLine}"; //your data
    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(dataasstring);
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

Alternatively, you could skip the stream approach entirely and just use the following:

```
string dataasstring = $"[{DateTime.Now.Hour}:{DateTime.Now.Minute}][Log]{Context.User.Username}:  {Context.Message.Content}{Environment.NewLine}";
File.AppendAllText(path, dataasstring);
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method, I did have to change a tiny messup you made but it was a simple mistake (You named the file stream stream, but used fs still xD) Thanks though, srsly!

Comment: It doesn't write to file, at all xD

Comment: Try changing the `FileStream` constructor to `new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)`

Comment: (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write)) Does nothing still,

Comment: @michaelukz I'm not sure, then. Try using the second method above.